# Linespacing in musixtex

Tags: musixtex

I am writing down music for a Spanish church service in musixtex. This song has two verses and at the end uses voltas. As a result, the space between two lines is not sufficient and the lyrics andthe voltas overlap.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs1{1}
\nobarnumbers
\resetlyrics
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}
\generalsignature{-1}
\setlyrics{padre1}{Pa-dre nues-tro tu {que es}-tás en los {que a}-man la ver-dad. Has {que el} rei-no que por ti se dio lle-gue pro-{nto a} nues-tro co-ra-zón, {que el} a-mor,__ que tu hi-jo__ nos de-jó, e-{{se a}}-mor. Rei-ne ya_ en no-so-tros. }
\setlyrics{padre2}{{Y en} el pan de {la u}-ni-dad, Cris-to da-nos tu la paz y ol-vi-da-te de nues-tro mal, {si ol}-vi-da-mos el de los de-más, no per-mi-tas,_ que cai-ga-mos_ en ten-ta-ción, oh se-ñor, {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} y ten pie-dad del mun-do.}
\assignlyrics1{padre1,padre2}
\resetlyrics
\startpiece
%\znotes\llyr\lyroffset{-1}\lyr
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu dd\Dqbu ff\Dqbl hh\en\bar
\NOtes\wh{g}\en\bar
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu cc \Dqbu ee\Dqbu gg\en\bar
\NOTes\wh{f}\en\bar
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu ff \Dqbu hh\Dqbl jj\en\bar
\NOtes\qlp{k}\cl{k}\hl{j}\en\bar
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu ff \Dqbu hh\Dqbl jj\en\bar
\NOtes\qlp{k}\cl{k}\hl{j}\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu ff\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOtes\isluru0k\cl{k}\cl{k}\tslur0k\hl{k}\Dqbl kl\en\bar
\NOtes\cl{m}\isluru0m\cl{m}\qlp{m}\tslur0m\cl{m}\cl{l}\cl{k}\en\bar
\NOtes\hlp{j}\Dqbl kj\en\bar
\NOtes\wh{h}\en
\Setvolta{1}
\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}\changecontext
%ENDING1
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu hh\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOTes\hlp{j}\cl{j}\cu{e}\en\bar
\NOtes\cu{ef}\hu{d}\en
\Setvolta{2}\endvoltabox\rightrepeat
%ENDING2
\NOtes\verses\lyricsoff\ds\cu{h}\Dqbu hh\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOTes\wh{j}\en\bar
\NOtes\cu{ef}\hu{d}\en
\Endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

I have already played around with the `\lyrraise{}{}` command, but that has the effect that there will be space between the lyrics and the music that is on top of them. The lyrics and voltas still overlap. Instead I would like the space to be below the lyrics, to create additional space between lyrics and the following line of music. That also makes more sense as the lyrics belong to the music on top of them.
Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT: Code has been completed to be compilable as it is.

Comment: I couldn't compile your score segment, could you please give a full example?

Comment: I have edited the code snippet. It compiles for me as it is and leads to a result in musixtexs 3-pass system. The original problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add two lines to adjust verticle space

```
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne % set verticle space in one staff score
\setsongraise1{5mm} % raise verticle space of the lyrycs
```

[image: After 3 pass]

Full script

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne % set verticle space in one staff score
\setsongraise1{5mm} % raise verticle space of the lyrycs
%\setinterinstrument0{5\Interligne}% set verticle space in multi staff score
%\lyrraise{1}{b10pt}
%\hardspace{4mm}% for horizon space
\setstaffs1{1}
\nobarnumbers
\resetlyrics
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}
\generalsignature{-1}
\setlyrics{padre1}{Pa-dre nues-tro tu {que es}-tás en los {que a}-man la ver-dad. Has {que el} rei-no que por ti se dio lle-gue pro-{nto a} nues-tro co-ra-zón, {que el} a-mor,__ que tu hi-jo__ nos de-jó, e-{{se a}}-mor. Rei-ne ya_ en no-so-tros. }
\setlyrics{padre2}{{Y en} el pan de {la u}-ni-dad, Cris-to da-nos tu la paz y ol-vi-da-te de nues-tro mal, {si ol}-vi-da-mos el de los de-más, no per-mi-tas,_ que cai-ga-mos_ en ten-ta-ción, oh se-ñor, {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} {{}} y ten pie-dad del mun-do.}
\assignlyrics1{padre1,padre2}
\resetlyrics
\startpiece
%\znotes\llyr\lyroffset{-1}\lyr
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu dd\Dqbu ff\Dqbl hh\en\bar
\NOtes\wh{g}\en\bar
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu cc \Dqbu ee\Dqbu gg\en\bar
\NOTes\wh{f}\en\bar
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu ff \Dqbu hh\Dqbl jj\en\bar
\NOtes\qlp{k}\cl{k}\hl{j}\en\bar
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu ff \Dqbu hh\Dqbl jj\en\bar
\NOtes\qlp{k}\cl{k}\hl{j}\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu ff\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOtes\isluru0k\cl{k}\cl{k}\tslur0k\hl{k}\Dqbl kl\en\bar
\NOtes\cl{m}\isluru0m\cl{m}\qlp{m}\tslur0m\cl{m}\cl{l}\cl{k}\en\bar
\NOtes\hlp{j}\Dqbl kj\en\bar
\NOtes\wh{h}\en
\Setvolta{1}
\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}\changecontext
%ENDING1
\NOtes\qp\Dqbu hh\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOTes\hlp{j}\cl{j}\cu{e}\en\bar
\NOtes\cu{ef}\hu{d}\en
\Setvolta{2}\endvoltabox\rightrepeat
%ENDING2
\NOtes\verses\lyricsoff\ds\cu{h}\Dqbu hh\en\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}\changecontext
\NOTes\wh{j}\en\bar
\NOtes\cu{ef}\hu{d}\en
\Endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

You should use 3 passing to compile, can use a `makefile`

```
# Author: c275633094@gmail.com
# Date: 05-04-2018
# MusiXTeX musixdoc tutorial example makefile
## First, set the main filename = YOUR_TEX_FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_.TEX
# $ make, to run commands in this file
# $ make read, to read the pdf file
# $ make clean, to clean the inter file

filename=musicnotes

all:
    latex ${filename}
    musixflx ${filename}
    bibtex ${filename}||true
    latex ${filename}
    makeindex ${filename}
    latex ${filename}
    latex ${filename}
    dvips -e0 ${filename}
    ps2pdf ${filename}.ps


read:
    evince ${filename}.pdf &

oread:
    okular ${filename}.pdf

clean:
    -rm -f *.aux
    -rm -f *.ps
    -rm -f *.dvi
    -rm -f *.idx
    -rm -f *.ilg
    -rm -f *.ind
    -rm -f *.mx1
    -rm -f *.mx2
    -rm -f *.log
    -rm -f *.toc
    -rm -f *.bbl
    -rm -f *.blg
    -rm -f *.out
    -rm -f make/bib
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. For the 3-pass system I already use a makefile, albeit a much less sophisticated one. Thanks a billion!